# mysql join query. however, some data doesn't have a joined data

Tags: mysql, join

I want to make a query.

what i exactly want to do is ~

i have two table one is called `model`, another is called `model_image`.

i want to select `no`, `name`, `mobile` from `model` and `img_name` from `model_image` if data exist.

```
select m.no, m.name, m.display_name, m.mobile, i.img_name 
from model as m
left join model_image as i on m.no = i.model_no 
order by i.sort desc 
limit 1
```

So, I made this query but I have no idea about how can I get data which doesn't have any data in model_image table.

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you ~

Following query works Thank you ~

```
select m.no, m.name, m.display_name, m.mobile, IFNULL(i.img_name, '') AS img_name
from model as m
left join (
    SELECT a.model_no, a.img_name
    FROM model_image AS a
    JOIN (SELECT model_no, MAX(sort) AS maxsort
          FROM model_image
          GROUP BY model_no) AS b
    ON a.model_no = b.model_no AND a.sort = b.maxsort) AS i
on m.no = i.model_no
```

[image]

Comment: this should be achieved by the `left join` you are using. Are you sure you don't miss it because you limit your result to one row only?

Comment: yes i want to get model information and only one model image which is the highest sorting number. each model has many pictures but i want to display front page only one picture and name .. so i wrote down limit 1.

Comment: The `LIMIT` clause applies to the whole query, not 1 row per model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the highest sorting image per model, you need to do that in a subquery, and join that with the `model` table.

```
select m.no, m.name, m.display_name, m.mobile, IFNULL(i.img_name, '') AS img_name
from model as m
left join (
    SELECT a.model_no, a.img_name
    FROM model_image AS a
    JOIN (SELECT model_no, MAX(sort) AS maxsort
          FROM model_image
          GROUP BY model_no) AS b
    ON a.model_no = b.model_no AND a.sort = b.maxsort) AS i
on m.no = i.model_no
```

See [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1) for an explanation of the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `left join`, which is correct and will give you results from `model` which don't have corresponding row in `model_image`

However, you are sorting it by a column from the second table. In left join, every row that appears only on the first table, will get `null` on all columns from the second table.
So as a result, all rows where there's no image will have null as your sorting column. as a result, since you limit your result to 1, you will not get the nulls which are on the bottom of your result set

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So is it any way to input "or m.no = null"?